# android read nfc and paste to browser textbox

Tags: android, nfc

is there a app that can read a nfc and paste same informations directly into a textbox in a browser?
I would use nfc tag to login users on my web app.
I tried some app, but i can't do it.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Web NFC](https://web.dev/nfc/) on Android to read NFC tags.

```js
document.querySelector("#scanButton").onclick = async () => {
  const ndef = new NDEFReader();
  // Prompt user to allow website to interact with NFC devices.
  await ndef.scan();

  // When user taps NFC tag, a `reading` event is fired.
  ndef.onreading = (event) => {
    // Assuming there's only one "text" record in the NDEF message.
    const record = event.message.records[0];
    const textDecoder = new TextDecoder(record.encoding);
    const decodedData = textDecoder.decode(record.data);

    // Paste `decodedData` in an `<input>` HTML element.
    document.querySelector("input").value = decodedData;
  };
};
```

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: perfect! exactly i wanted!

Comment: a question: could be possible to ask to enable nfc on page load, instead after a click?

Comment: It is not possible. A user gesture is always required.  See https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/docs/security/permissions-for-powerful-web-platform-features.md#baseline_secure-contexts_top_level-frames_user-gesture for more details

Comment: and how to read data? it give me a DataView...is there a better way instead read any bytes?

Comment: Check out https://web.dev/nfc/ to learn more about to handle other NFC records (text, url, etc...)